# Random number from a series of random numbers in Java?

Tags: java, random

Say i have five variables a,b,c,d and e which are all assigned a random number from five different ranges corresponding to to the five variables a to e.

Is there a way to assign a sixth variable say x, that chooses a random number from a range with upper value equal to the total of a+b+c+d+e?

for example, say :-

```
a=5      (range 0-10)
b=1043   (range 0-2000)
c=37     (range 0-38)
d=2      (range 0-100)
e=20     (range 5-30)

then x = (random number) (range 5- 1107)
```

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried?

Comment: Why does the range of x start with 5?

Comment: By the way, welcome to SO.  Here, since you're new, you should take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about).  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1))
```

Where Min = a and Max = a+b+c+d+e

Comment: Consider `min = 0`, `max = 9`, your code returns an `int` in range [0, 8), which I believe is not what OP wants...

Comment: Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1)) can be used

Comment: that's true, but that's not what you put.

Comment: If you want to update your answer you can do it with [edit] button under your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

From `java.util.Random`:

```
Random rand = new Random();

rand.nextInt(X); 
//returns an `int` in range: [0,X)
```

So, if you have `a`, `b`, ..., `n`, to get a number in between 0 and the sum of the variables, we do:

```
rand.nextInt(a + b + ... + n + 1); //returns an `int` in range [0, sum(a,b,...,n)]
```

As other users have suggested, you can also use `Math.random()`; however, `Math.random()` returns a `double` in range: `[0,1)`.  So, if you have `min = 0`, `max = 9`, and want a number between `[0,9]`, then you need:

```
Min + (int)(Math.round((Math.random() * (Max - Min))))
//need to cast to int since Math.round(double returns a long)

or you could do:

Min + (int)(Math.random() * (Max - Min + 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I missunderstood your problem, but you just need to sum each var and do the same thing. Some answers already showed that.

It is just a algorithm problem.

```
int lra = 0;    // lower range of a
int ura = 10;   // upper range of a
int lrb = 0;
int urb = 2000;
// a couple of ranges for each var...

int a = lra + ((int) (Math.random() * (ura - lra)));
// the same for each var...

int lrs = lra + lrb + ...; // sum of lower ranges...
int urs = ura + urb + ...; // sum of upper ranges

int x = lrs + ((int) (Math.random() * (urs - lrs)));
```

Comment: Thanks all, got a few ideas to work with. Can't believe how many replies i have had in 2 hours.No reason for the lower range of x, this is just a general value. I'll see how i get on and post my results, once again many thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the job

```
            Random generator = new Random();
            generator.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());
            long range = a+b+c+d+e;
            long fraction = (long)(range * generator.nextDouble());
            randomNumber =  (int)(fraction);
```